# Scio Scala : SCOLLECTION TO LONG

Tags: scala, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, spotify-scio

I am getting the max(a) of a pipeline in scala so the result is a `SCollection[Long]` and I want to transform the type to `Long` because I want after to substract the max(a) from min(a) and it's not possible to do it if the type is not `Long`.

I have tried to use `asInstanceOf[Long]` but it didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

```scala
val max = pipe.map(_.a).max              
val min = pipe.map(_.a).min           
val diff = max - min
```

Comment: `min` and `max` give you a collection of a single element. I'm not familiar with Scio but you need to look at how to convert /materialize such distributed collection to an actual value.

Comment: @GaëlJ Thank you for your response, I have researched that but I am not getting a solution that works until now...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `materialize` to extract the max and min values from the SCollection as a closed Tap. The Tap will be available once the pipeline completes successfully. materialize() must be called before the ScioContext is run e.g.

```
 val max =  pipe.map(_.a).max.materialize
 val min =  pipe.map(_.a).min.materialize
 val result = sc.run().waitUntilDone()
 max.get(result).value.next() - min.get(result).value.next()
```